# mmoreram/gearman-bundle Symfony implementation in php

Tags: symfony, bundle, gearman

I would like to use  mmoreram/gearman-bundle in Symfony. I already installed it, but when i call

```
php app/console gearman:job:execute PrGwBundleGearmanWorkerPrWorker~doSomething
```

I only get an overview an no result from the Job itself.

Also, I didn't understand yet how to call a Job from inside php. The doku doesn't really tell me how and there are - unfortunately - no tuts in the web for it :(

I think I first have to create a instance of $gearman. But how, there is no explanation of it :(
http://gearmanbundle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/running_jobs.html

It would be great if someone could help me getting into the bundle so that I can use it :

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Could you please copy here your worker definition?

Comment: I will search it in the backups and post it asap

Answer (score 1):

You have to run something like

```
php app/console gearman:job:execute PrGwBundleGearmanWorkerPrWorker --no-interaction
```

Then your worker is started and running.

You can call a function on your job worker like this:

```
$gearmanClient->doBackgroundJob('PrGwBundleGearmanWorkerPrWorker~doSomething', $payload);
```

This will execute the doSomething Method on your PrGwBundleGearmanWorkerPrWorker.

You can see a list of all defined workers with:

```
php app/console gearman:worker:list
```

and get details of an worker with:

```
php app/console gearman:worker:describe PrGwBundleGearmanWorkerPrWorker
```

Then you will get an output containing a line starting with

```
@Worker\supervisord
```

The command behind this, can be used to start the worker from the commandline.